# Count number of executions of batch-script

Tags: windows, batch-file, count, execution

This is my problem, I've got a batch-script that I can't modify (lets call it foo) and I would like to count how many times/day this script is executed - to keep track of that data.

Preferably, I would like to write the number of executions with date and exit-code to some kind of log file.

So my question is if this is possible and in that case - how? To create a batch-script/something that works in the background and writes every execution of foo to a log.

(I know this would be easy if I could modify foo but I can't. Also, everything is running on WinXP machines.)

Comment: You want something for nothing here. Modify the batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper script that does the logging and calls the existing script. Then use the wrapper in place of the original script

Comment: Sadly no. I am looking for something that would not change anything in the current computer-setup. A wrapper is a bit to big of a project since calls have to be changed through the whole environment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a program that interrogates the Task Manager.

See http://www.netomatix.com/ProcDiagnostics.aspx

You could, for example, write a simple Console app which runs on a timer; every 5 seconds it checks that your foo application process exists. If it finds that it does, it assumes that find as the start time of the application; if it doesn't find it, it assumes the application has now closed and logs that information. It wouldn't be accurate to the second by any means, but would give you a rough approximation of when the thing is running and closing.

Comment: This sounds a bit over the top, is there really no easier way?

Comment: If you can't modify the existing application then I'm afraid I don't really see another way. Running a timer inside a console app which checks what applications are executing is really the only sure way of knowing when and how many times your foo application is running. If your foo app is doing any kind of logging already then you could maybe dechiper things that way, but assuming it is not recording anything (any input to a database at all from it?) then the process monitoring is the way to go.

Comment: @mattssok: Consider your batch script an arbitrary application. Can you track the count of executions of Word.exe or Calc.exe? It's all the same. If you have no control over the file (cannot modify the source, cannot rename it and substitute with your own wrapper script), then you are left with little choice.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to configure Process Monitor
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to capture the information you require